# React processing of json

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting the following response from a service.

```
[ { _id: { month: 2 }, total: 4333 },
  { _id: { month: 1 }, total: 8455 } ]
```

How can i attain the values in react, whatever I have tried gives me an object. Below is the code I ahev tried as per other questions on stackoverflow but havent helped me.

```
 console.log(getAllSalesValue);
    var tifOptions = [];

    Object.keys(getAllSalesValue).forEach(function(key) {
        tifOptions.push(getAllSalesValue[key]);
    });

    console.log("2");
    console.log(tifOptions);
```

The above gives me the below output which again needs to be processing.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "attain the values"? What do you want to do with this response?

Comment: display them on my web page in react

Comment: Suggestion: When you want to create a new array from an existing on, use `map()` instead of `forEach()`: `var tifOptions = Object.keys(getAllSAlesValue).map(function(key) { return getAllSalesValue[key]; }`

Comment: You can access the members of the object directly with `tifOptions[0].id.month` or `tifOptions[0].total` for example. You might even `map()` over the `tifOptions` array to create React components to display the data. It is difficult to provide any more details without some more context about how this fits into your react app. We can provide more help if you give a working example of your React code that shows what you have done so far.

Comment: Got it to work via    const { classes } = this.props;
    const getAllSalesValue = this.props.getAllSales;
    //console.log("1");
   // console.log(getAllSalesValue);
    var tifOptions = [];

    Object.keys(getAllSalesValue).forEach(function(key) {
        tifOptions.push(getAllSalesValue[key]);
    });

    tifOptions.map(item=>{
      console.log(item._id.month);
      console.log(item.total);
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work.

```
const { classes } = this.props;
    const getAllSalesValue = this.props.getAllSales;
    //console.log("1");
   // console.log(getAllSalesValue);
    var tifOptions = [];

    Object.keys(getAllSalesValue).forEach(function(key) {
        tifOptions.push(getAllSalesValue[key]);
    });

    tifOptions.map(item=>{
      console.log(item._id.month);
      console.log(item.total);
    })
```

Thanks Code-Apprentice for the pointers and suggestions